# How to bind content of tag into into directive's scope?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

Say I have a directive like such:

```
<my-directive>This is my entry!</my-directive>
```

How can I bind the content of the element into my directive's scope?

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        scope : {
            entry : "" //what goes here to bind "This is my entry" to scope.entry?
        },
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<textarea>{{entry}}</textarea>"
        link: function (scope, elm, attr) {
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: How does the content get added to the html in the first place? Usually it's the $scope that defines what to show in the view and not the way around.

Comment: The content for this element is added on the server side. The angular templates are generated using a PHP application, as the content isn't available RESTfully in this case.

I could just add the content as an attribute, but given this directive will act like a `<textarea>`, for the sake of developer understanding, I would love to maintain the usage of a `<textarea>`.

Comment: I think older versions of IE don't like directives with element names, which is why attribute or class is preferred.  Not sure if that's part of your use case, but it's worth considering Grandma's IE6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's much simpler solution to the ones already given. As far as I understand, you want to bind contents of an element to scope during initialization of directive.

Given this html:

```
<textarea bind-content ng-model="entry">This is my entry!</textarea>
```

Define `bind-content` as follows:

```
directive('bindContent', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue($element.text());
    }
  }
})
```

Here's a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/QnTWGRXYctaBPbQpgQ34?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

You will want to add a **template** config to your directive.

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
    scope : {
      entry : "=" //what goes here to bind "This is my entry" to scope.entry?
    },
    template: "<div>{{ entry }}</div>", //**YOU DIDN'T HAVE A TEMPLATE**
    restrict: "E",
    link: function (scope, elm, attr) {
      //You don't need to do anything here yet
    }
  };
});

myApp.controller('fooController', function($scope){
  $scope.foo = "BLAH BLAH BLAH!";
});
```

And then use your directive like this:

```
<div ng-controller="fooController">
  <!-- sets directive "entry" to "foo" from parent scope-->
  <my-directive entry="foo"></my-directive>
</div>
```

And angular will turn that into:

```
<div>THIS IS MY ENTRY</div>
```

Assuming that you have angular setup correctly and are including this JS file onto your page.

**EDIT**

It sounds like you want to do something like the following:

```
<my-directive="foo"></my-directive>
```

This isn't possible with ELEMENT directives. It is, however, with attribute directives. Check the following.

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
    template: "<div>{{ entry }}</div>", //**YOU DIDN'T HAVE A TEMPLATE**
    restrict: "A",
    scope : {
      entry : "=myDirective" //what goes here to bind "This is my entry" to scope.entry?
    },
    link: function (scope, elm, attr) {
      //You don't need to do anything here yet
    }
  };
});
```

Then use it like this:

```
<div my-directive="foo"></div>
```

This will alias the value passed to **my-directive** onto a scope variable called **entry**. Unfortunately, there is no way to do this with an element-restricted directive. What is preventing it from happening isn't Angular, it is the html5 guidelines that make what you are wanting to do impossible. You will have to use an attribute directive instead of an element directive.

Comment: Ah, yes. I forgot the template. I added it in and you can see what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm trying to move data from where the directive is used into the link function. This is easily accomplished when the data is included as an attribute to the directive's tag, but it's unclear how to grab the content from inside the tag.

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: How about now? There is an example of how to use your directive inside a controller. And I fixed the scope declaration in the directive config.

Comment: I'm looking to bind content from inside the directive tag into the directive's scope, not using an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found a solution. It relies on the transclude function of directives. It works, but I need to better understand transclusion before being sure this is the right way.

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: false,
        template:   '<form>' +
                        '<textarea ng-model="entry"></textarea>' +
                        '<button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>' +
                    '</form>',
        transclude : true,
        compile : function(element,attr,transclude){

            return function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

                transclude(scope, function(originalElement){
                    scope.entry = originalElement.text(); // this is where you have reference to the original element.
                });


                scope.submit = function(){
                    console.log('update entry');
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: While this works, you're placing the key of the value (`entry`) in two separate places (template and linking function). It's better to keep `ng-model="entry"` as it is, but use `ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue` instead of `scope.entry` as in my answer.